# Recover source host of lost mapped drives on Windows 2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, mappeddrive

I have a legacy Windows 2003 Server that hosts an MS SQL server DB. The mdf and ldf files of said DB are stored on network mapped drives. One day the DB encountered errors only for us to find out that the mapped drives are gone. Is there any way to check or retrace the hosts of those mapped drives? And restore them for the DB to work properly again?

Comment: did you checled `net use`?

Comment: What do you mean check or retrace the hosts of those mapped drives? Do you mean find the server where those files were?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you lost the network drives the SQL DB files were on. 
This is a very odd construct. 
You could find the drives in regedit under Computer\HKEY_USERS\ {user guid} \Network if they havent been removed with net use /del ie. 
If you find the path there, you could try to recreate the exact drives, paths and files. If you have consitent files at the right location SQL server should start the dbs again.